# How can I get my Sapphire Radeon 7850 to output in "1080p"?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdmi, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

I have a Radeon 7850 connected to a Vizio 3D compatible TV. The TV has a function to parse and display SBS encoded content. On my old graphics card (a Radeon 5770) I just had to select the 1080p option in the catalyst control center.

In this mode my TV reported the output mode as "1080p", with the new card the TV reports "1920x1080". I cannot figure out what the difference in between the 2 signals but the "1920x1080" cannot be switched into 3D mode by the TV.

Weirdly, before windows starts the (in the Bios and so forth) the computer outputs in "1080p" so I know the card is capable of it. As soon as the blue login screen comes up though it changes back to the "1920x1080".

I've tried everthing I can think of. Updated my drivers from 13.3b3 to 13.4, then even tried the 13.5 beta (Which I'm still on this moment). Tried all the "optimized" HD settings in catalyst, even the 720p modes show the resolution from the TV and not the "720p" (which it used to do on the old card when I had to lower the resolution of games)

Comment: 1080p == 1920x1080; 720p == 1280x720

Comment: @nerdwaller I am aware of this. Apparently the TV isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on it and found a software solution to display SBS 3D content but continued to update my graphics drivers periodically. I do not know which driver update fixed it as I did not notice until recently but it has resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.avsforum.com/t/1383838/3dtv-not-detecting-3d-signal-from-pc#post_21447586) in another forum suggests you'll need to set your TV as your primary display (maybe only display?) to get 3D output.

Some other posts there seem to suggest that changing the refresh rate on the PC may be necessary as well.

Comment: I've seen that post, but on my machine the TV is the only display and I've tried all the standard refresh rates. (24,50 and 60 at both the 720 and 1080 resolutions)